# Position footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly complex layout that I am building, it relies on a is affected by height, and min-height's so the usual tricks to position the footer at the bottom aren't working.

Given my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/3/) how can I position the footer at the bottom when the content is a lot or minimal?

Here is some of the css I am currently using:

```
body, html, #wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.header {
    height: 30%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.main { 
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.main .content {
    height: 2000px; 
    background-color: aquamarine;    
    padding-bottom:80px; 
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the sticky footer trick. Wrap all of your content in a wrapper excluding the footer, set `min-height:100%` and `margin: -(footer height)` on said wrapper to keep it at the bottom:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/6/)

**UPDATE**

You can take the `header` section out and use CSS `calc()` to adjust the height:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/7/)

Comment: You will note the header element height: 30% no longer works with your solution (change it to 70% - does nothing.)

Comment: @shenku updated the answer. Just needed a tweak since their wasn't a definded height on the header's parent. Unlike bgoldst's answer using this method keeps the footer at the bottom at all times. If you remove the height from his/her answer the footer will not stay at the bottom

Comment: Awesome, I've done the above on my .main element instead of wrapping it, see http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/9/ - thanks.

Comment: any idea why it doesnt work with a fixed height header? http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/10/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want the footer to sit at the bottom of the content box.

One solution is to make the content box `position:relative` and move the footer inside it, so that its `position:absolute` will bind it to the content box, and the `bottom:0` will achieve the desired effect of having it sit against the bottom of said content box.

See http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/5/.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="body-content">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#" class="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="content container">
                <p>Content</p>
                <div class="footer"> <!-- moved up into content container -->
                    <p>Footer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(relevant) CSS:

```
.main .content {
    height: 2000px; 
    background-color: aquamarine;    
    padding-bottom:80px; 
    position:relative;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear if there is not much content in the content section, the footer should still be on the bottom of the page. So in this scenario the footer should still be on the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/8/